# Rotate quaternion by body yaw

Tags: ros-kinetic, tf2, quaternion, yaw, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to change a quaternion's body-fixed yaw?

Using `Matrix3x3`'s `getRPY` and then `setRPY` doesn't work, because this is about the axes, fixed to the initial orientation, so it's fixed yaw, not body yaw.

Using `getEulerYPR` and then `setEulerYPR` doesn't work as well, because yaw rotation it the first, and it gets affected the following pitch and roll rotation.

I think `getEulerRPY`/`setEulerRPY` might work, but there are no such functions in the `tf` and `tf2` libraries.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304273/rotate-quaternion-by-body-yaw/) by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks working (`pq` - input quaternion):

```
tf::Quaternion q;
q.setRPY(0, 0, angle_to_rotate);
pq = pq * q;
```

---

Originally posted by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) with karma: 11 on 2018-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

try to use:

```
tf::Quaternion rotation;
rotation = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(Roll,Pitch,Yaw);
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [okalachev](https://answers.ros.org/users/31609/okalachev/) on 2018-09-26**:
The problem is, that if I keep roll and pitch, changing the yaw, that would be rotation about *extrinsic* Z axis, while I need about *intrinsic* (body-attached) one.